# Open Babel running .Net C# Process, doesn't work on deployed website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, process, openbabel

Due to some circumstances, I was ask to develop a page that uses Process in .Net C# to call the function through command prompt. 
The code works perfectly Fine on visual studio, but when deployed on an IIS server. the Process doesn't seems to work, I've debugged and find out the process itself works. but the open Babel command doesn't work, i did double check and the identity i supply with should be alright, i did even supply it with admin privilege but still doesn't work. it doesn't even pop or error, it just simply ignored it and go through the commands. 
I put the command into a .bat file, with some extra command to test if the .bat works. everything is fine until the command with open babel, then process just doesn't seem react with the command.

> obabel %1 -O %2 --gen2d

this is the command i supply it with, %1 is the input file while %2 is the output file name. A very simple conversion. **Note:** everything is fine, just only the open babel command got ignored in the entire file. and I've tried to supply it with **admin** privilege, still doesn't work. the open babel can be used if directly used with **command prompt** on the server, or through **visual studio**. but it doesn't work if i deployed it through IIS server.

Comment: Have you tried running application pool using LocalSystem account?

Comment: Doesn't work, same reaction as the admin privilege. nothing

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, after all kinds of modification. 
it seems like i have to provide a physical path to Open Babel.exe in the .bat file, and same as the parameter file i supply it with.
It's risky solution, but at least it solves the problem.